# Is a topological space pseudo-metrizable if and only if it is regular and paracompact?

Tags: general-topology

Is a topological space pseudo-metrizable if and only if it is regular and paracompact ?

I have a link to a reference , "General Topology" , Kelley , page 127 , theorem 18 .  Also note a paracompact space has a locally finite base, and so as required there, a sigma-locally finite base.

On page 128, the proof of lemma 20 shows, if the assumption that the space is T1 is dropped, that a regular paracompact space is pseudo-metrizable.

Comment: https://ia800501.us.archive.org/16/items/GeneralTopology/Kelley-GeneralTopology.pdf  was the link i forgot to include

Comment: A paracompact space does not always have such a base. A space with such a base is paracompact, that much is true.

Comment: Henno Brandsma thanks I see my mistake, I was thinking an open refinement of a base is also a base but obviously that isn't true.  However, it is true that a regular space which has a sigma locally finite base is pseudo-metrizable.

Comment: Indeed, the $T_1$-ness only "bridges the gap" between a metric and a pseudometric (where we can have $d(x,y) = 0$ for distinct points). This already follows from the quotient space argument.

Comment: Henno Brandsma are you saying that the theorem that a T1 regular space with sigma locally finite base is metrizable implies that if its just regular with signa locally finite base its pseudometrizable ?  I dont see how one would take a quotient of the given space to get another that satisfies the hypotheses of that theorem

Comment: i should add, i came to the conclusion it would be pseudometrizable by looking at the proof for the T1 case an realizing if you dont require T1 the same proof works to show its pseudometrizable

Comment: Yes, if $X$ has a sigma-locally-finite base and is regular, take the quotient space $Y$ under the Kolmogorov relation that $xRy$ iff the singletons $x$ and $y$ have equal closures. This still has such a base and is regular $T_1$ and so is metrisable. Now lift the metric back to a pseudometric on $X$ in the trivial way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, paracompact is not enough. Consider the Sorgenfrey Line or the Double arrow space.

We really need $\sigma$-locally finite base or a $\sigma$-discrete base.